# laravel dusk random select prevent the first option

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

This is a select

```
<select id='fruit' name='fruit'>
    <option value="">please select one fruit</option>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
</select>
```

This is my test

```
/** @test  */
public function form_test()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->select('fruit');
    }
}
```

When I testing the form, I need to random select fruit but not the first "please select one fruit" element, but when I use `->select()`, sometimes it select the first "please select one fruit" element, is there a way to prevent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `disable` to its property.

```
<select id='fruit' name='fruit'>
     <option value="" disabled>please select one fruit</option>
     <option value="apple">apple</option>
     <option value="banana">banana</option>
     <option value="orange">orange</option>
</select>
```